# Factory does not execute $http.get

Tags: angularjs

My factory does not seem to execute my `$http.get`. Here's my controller:

```
app.factory("myService", function($http) {

    var myService = {
        retrieve: function(id, type) {

        var retrievedData = {
            device: {},
            childDevices: [],
            error: {}
        };
        .
        .
        .
        $http.get(url, headers)
        .success(function(data, status) {
            // some data post-processing
            // some logs
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            // some data post-processing
            // some logs
        });

        return retrievedData;

    };

    return myService;

});
```

The logs within the `$http.get` do not print.

I read somewhere I need to use `promise`, but most examples I saw return `$http.get` directly. I don't want to return `$http.get` right away as I need to make some modification on the data in the factory rather than in the controller.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling the function? Returning `retrievedData` is not a great idea - the caller wouldn't know *when* to use `retrievedData`(when you return it, it would be empty). You don't have to return `$http.get()` directly, every time you chain a .then(), that creates a new promise for the value *after* your post-processing, so if you `return $http.get().then().then()` (or in your case, `.success()`), you'd be returning a promise for the final value.

Comment: What you posted is a service, not a controller. And it's not valid code, so we don't know if $http should be called or not in the real code. Post the real code.

Comment: @JBNizet I deliberately posted the factory only. It's getting invoked by my controller anyway (code not here), as I have logs printing outside of `$http.get` but not inside.

Comment: @Sacho For my promise, can I still use `$http.get(...).success(function(data, status){...}).error(function(data, status){...});` instead of `$http.get(...).then(function(data){}, function(error){})`?

Comment: The logs in .success() and .error() not printing are not really related to what you're returning there - this is why you should post the real code, as JBNizet said.

Answer (score -1):

Because when you return your `retrievedData` it hasn't been retrieved yet. That's why you should use promises:

```
   app.factory("myService", function ($http,$q) {
     var myService = {
     retrieve: function (id, type) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var retrievedData = {
            device: {},
            childDevices: [],
            error: {}
        };

        $http.get(url, headers).then(function (data) {
                // success do your success things here and return data 
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            function (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });


        return deferred.promise;

      }
  };

  return myService;

});
```

// usage

```
myService.retrive(id,type).then(function(data){
// data retrived
})
```

Comment: What if I want `deferred.resolve(retrievedData)`? The processed data should be contained in `retrievedData`. Is it alright?

Answer (score -1):

in angular js promise is used for returning response which come from backend. in your code `retrievedData` return before response come from backend. that's why angular use promise. so when response come from backend it execute success block and success block resolve the promise using `deferred.resolve(data)` . when error occure then error block get execute and it rejected the promise `deferred.reject(err)` .but when it resolve the promise it return the response data.

Service Code:

```
app.factory("myService", function ($http,$q) {
var myService = {
    retrieve: function (id, type) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var retrievedData = {
            device: {},
            childDevices: [],
            error: {}
        };

        $http.get(url, headers).then(function (data) {
                // after success this block execute
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            function (err) {
              //after error this block execute
                deferred.reject(err);
            });


        return deferred.promise;

    }
};

return myService;
});
```

controller code :

```
//calling retrive function 
myService.retrive(id,type).then(fucntion(data){
  ...
})
.catch(function(){
...
})
```

Comment: For my promise, can I still use `$http.get(...).success(function(data, status){...}).error(function(data, status){...});` instead of `$http.get(...).then(function(data){}, function(error){})`?